# Poor Acceleration after certain speed

Tags: chevrolet, acceleration, captiva

I have Chevrolet Captiva and for last 2 months I am experiencing some strange issue that on the highway, once my car reaches 90 km/h or above, after a few seconds it fails to accelerate. If I restart the ignition while running, the problem gets resolved. However sometime this issue doesn't appear. I checked my turbo and throttle body and there is no issue with them.

No check engine light at all. Any suggestions?

Comment: Although this probably isn't a transmission related issue, I would nevertheless specify in the question whether it's an automatic or a manual transmission. At what RPM does the problem occur? Engine related issues generally should be specified in terms of RPM, not in terms of km/h.

Comment: What year? Has it been serviced regularly?

Comment: Its Chevrolet Captiva 2008 DIESEL and this problem occurs after 2500 rpm. I clean MAF, O2 & throttle and Turbo sensor but still nothing works...not sure where the issue is.... ?